# Identify existence of keywords in document from list

Tags: java, lucene

I want to create a tag list for a Lucene document based on a pre-determined list.

So, if we have a document with the text

*Looking for a Java programmer with experience in Lucene*

and we have the keyword list (about 1000 items)

*java, php, lucene, c# [...]*

I want to identify that the keywords Java and Lucene exist in the document. 
Just doing a java OR php OR lucene will not work because then I will not know which keyword generated the hit.

Any suggestions on how to implement this in Lucene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works

```
FullTextSession fts = Search.getFullTextSession(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());

Query q = fts.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
    .forEntity(Offer.class).get()
    .keyword()
    .onField("id")
    .matching(myId)
    .createQuery();
Object[] dId = (Object[]) fts.createFullTextQuery(q, Offer.class)
    .setProjection(ProjectionConstants.DOCUMENT_ID)
    .uniqueResult();

if(dId != null){

    IndexReader indexReader = fts.getSearchFactory().getIndexReaderAccessor().open(Offer.class);

    TermFreqVector freq = indexReader.getTermFreqVector((Integer) dId[0], "description");

}
```

You have to remember to index the field with TermVector.YES in your hibernate search annotation for the field.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have one or more indexed fields, and you want to build your tag cloud based on the intersection of your keywords and the indexed terms for a document.

Your problem is very similar to highlighting, so the same ideas apply, you can either:

- re-analyze the stored fields of your Lucene document,
- use [term vectors](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermFreqVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) for fast access to your documents' stored fields.

Note that if you want to use term vectors, you need to enable them at compile time (see [Field.TermVector.YES documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.TermVector.html#YES) and [Field constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/index.html)).

Comment: It looks like TermVectors could be the ticket here. I'm using Hibernate Search, so I'll have a look if I can use this feature in this context